# How can I independently have images fade up and down in Processing?

Tags: processing

I've struggled with this question for some time and feel that I am missing the basic concepts that will let me answer it. This code is probably way off base.

I want to display about 40 png's randomly and continuously, one after another forever, about half a second apart. (This code does that.) But I want each one to fade up for 5 seconds, then fade down for 5 seconds.

Any effort I have made to programmatically trigger timed images interfers with efforts I have made to program a fade up/down in each one (e.g. instance of an object).

This is driving me crazy!

I hope I am overlooking something simple.

Or is this impossible?

Thanks.

```
PImage[] flowers = new PImage[40];
Bubble[] bubbles = new Bubble[40];

void setup() {
  size(1400, 800);
  for (int i = 0; i < flowers.length; i++) {
    flowers[i] = loadImage(i+".png");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
    int index = int(random(0, flowers.length));
    bubbles[i] = new Bubble(flowers[index], random(width), 200);
  }
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  tint(0, 150, 150, 20);
  image(flowers[int(random(40))], random(width), 200);
  delay(10);
}

 class Bubble {
  
  PImage img;
  float x;
  float y;
  
  Bubble(PImage tempImg, float tempX, float tempY){
   x = tempX;
   y = tempY;
   img = tempImg;
  } 
  
  void display(){
   imageMode(CENTER);
   image(img,x,y);
   y--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to run the posted example due to lack of 40 png images, but the following will fadeIn and fadeOut an image:

```
PImage img;
float transparency = 255;
boolean fadeOut = true;
boolean fadeIn = false;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  img = loadImage("http://www.paperhippo.com/images/wmwallpapers/Sequoia-:-Fog-1.jpeg");
}

void draw() {
  background(100);
  if (transparency > 0 && fadeOut) {
    transparency -= 1.0;
  } else {
    fadeIn = true;
    fadeOut = false;
  }

  if (transparency < 255.0 && fadeIn) {
    transparency += 1.0;
  } else {
    fadeOut = true;
    fadeIn = false;
  }
  tint(255, transparency);
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Alternate version which loads .png images from a 'data' folder in the sketch folder.  It's set initially for five images, but should be scalable.  The demo first fades in an image, then fades it out.  As fading out is complete, a new image is randomly set with an accompanying random xOffset and the cycle repeats.  I wasn't sure of the function of the 'Bubble' class so it was left out of the demo.

```
PImage[] img = new PImage[5];
int imgNum = 0;
int xOffset = 0;
float transparency = 0;

boolean fadeIn = true;
boolean fadeOut = false;

void setup() {
  size(1400, 600);
  for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i] = loadImage(i+".png");
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(100);
  if (transparency < 255.0 && fadeIn) {
    transparency += 1.0;
    println("fadeIn :", transparency);
    if (transparency == 255) {
      fadeIn = false;
      fadeOut = true;
    }
  }

  if (transparency > 0 && fadeOut) {
    transparency -= 1.0;
    println("fadeOut :", transparency);
    if (transparency == 0.0) {
      fadeIn = true;
      fadeOut = false;
      // set another image
      imgNum = (int)random(5);
      xOffset = (int)random(width-200);
      image(img[imgNum], xOffset, 0);
    }
  }

  tint(255, transparency);
  image(img[imgNum], xOffset, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Apodidae. Your example works, but does not address my problem: I want one (or many) images to fade up and down WHILE other images are fading up/down. Your example has them fading one after another, but NOT at the same time. Maybe this is not possible.